# reshape data to split one column into multiple columns based on delimiter in pandas or otherwise in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame({
'State':['C','B','D','A','C','B'],
'Contact':['alpha a. theta| beta','beta| alpha a. theta| delta','Theta','gamma| delta','alpha|Eta| gamma| delta','beta'],
'Timestamp':[911583000000,912020000000,912449000000,912742000000,913863000000,915644000000]})
```

How do I transform it so that the second column which has pipe separated data is broken out into different rows as follows:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
'State':['C','C','B','B','B','D','A','A','C','C','C','C','B'],
'Contact':['alpha a. theta','beta','beta','alpha a. theta','delta','Theta','gamma', 'delta','alpha','Eta','gamma','delta','beta'],
'Timestamp':[911583000000,911583000000,912020000000,912020000000,912020000000,912449000000,912742000000,912742000000,913863000000,913863000000,913863000000,913863000000,915644000000]})

print(df_in)
print(df_out)
```

I can use pd.melt but for that I already need to have the 'Contact' column broken out into multiple columns and not have all the contacts in one column separated by a delimiter.

Comment: Are you typing this out by hand, or will your list of values be a variable that can be manipulated before going into your dataframe?

Comment: it will be a csv file which can be imported into the dataframe

Comment: `df_in.Contact.str.split('\|\s*', expand=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the column, then merge on the index:

```
  df_in.Contact.str.split('|',expand=True).stack().reset_index()\
    .merge(df_in.reset_index(),left_on ='level_0',right_on='index')\
    .drop(['level_0','level_1','index','Contact'],1)
Out: 
                  0 State     Timestamp
0    alpha a. theta     C  911583000000
1              beta     C  911583000000
2              beta     B  912020000000
3    alpha a. theta     B  912020000000
4             delta     B  912020000000
5             Theta     D  912449000000
6             gamma     A  912742000000
7             delta     A  912742000000
8             alpha     C  913863000000
9               Eta     C  913863000000
10            gamma     C  913863000000
11            delta     C  913863000000
12             beta     B  915644000000
```

Comment: there is a slight problem with this solution. The  column "Contact" will split properly only if there are no other spacings. But the names are not like that there. The are like "alpha R. beta". so like real names. The extractall('(\\w+)') part breaks it out into individual words it seems. How do we modify this so that it just separates on the basis of the "|" separator?

Comment: I have modified the input and out by changing the names " "alpha" to alpha a. theta" to make it clearer. I am trying to use str.split('|'). But that does not quite do it.

Comment: @AlhpaDelta check the edit

Comment: Thanks! that looks perfect!!